# how can i differentiate gmail and facebook contacts contained in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, tableview

I am developing an application in xmpp.I have gmail and facebook contacts in a tableview.But i want to differentiate those contacts.For Example gmail contacts will shown by 'g' letter and facebook contacts will shown by 'f' letter.can any one help me for my question.

thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two sections for each of the Contact list:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}
```

Then you can give a header Title for each section:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"G"; // For Gmail
    } else
        return @"F"; // For facebook }
```

And then according to the section number, you can implement your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by creating a separate arrays for both the kinds of contacts.

All the best!!!